# Insert content using JQuery .append() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have existing div elements like this as tab:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-a">

</div>
```

I insert a JavaScript string array into that tab using this :

```
var full_list = "";

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    full_list = '<a href="#' + data[i].alias + '">' + full_list + data[i].name + '<br>';
}"</a>"

$(target).html(full_list);
```

And my content is displayed vertically in a single column like this:

```
Dairy products
Dancing Groups
Dancing Instructors
Data Communication Services
Data Networking & Cabling
Data Processing Equipment
Day Care/Montessori Schools
```

I want them to display in two columns such as:

```
Dairy products                 Data Networking & Cabling   
Dancing Groups                 Data Processing Equipment
Dancing Instructors            Day Care/Montessori Schools
Data Communication Services
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use a table with tr td inside the div

Comment: Are you sure you want to wrap every previous `full_list` value in ever more `<a href>` tags? And why is `</a>` only added once outside the for loop?

Comment: I would like to do with
<div class="col-md-6"></div>

Comment: Columns, display: flex, tables, ... CSS has many options for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `br` tag for links and set `column-count` `css` property to set the required column count as below.

```
.tab-pane {
  column-count: 2;
}
```

Here is a demonstration.

```css
.tab-pane {
  column-count: 2;
}

.tab-pane a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="tab-a">
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 1</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 2</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 3</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 4</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 5</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 6</a>
  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Sample link 7</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing a few things to achieve your goal as well as improve your code.

Your JS is doing weird things inside the `for` loop, I changed it to use the `reduce` function and the string template approach to be more elegant :

```
var fullList = data.reduce((list, current) => {
    return list + `<a href="#${current.alias}">${current.name}</a><br />`;
}, '');
```

Now to achieve your goal, all you need to add is the following CSS :

```
#tab-a {
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/ZXyLer) that illustrates the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a `br` for each item. You need to have a `br` for every second item:

```
 var full_list = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
 full_list += '<a href="#' + data[i].alias + '">' + data[i].name + "</a>" + ((i % 2) ? '<br>' : '');
      }

 $(target).html(full_list);
```

Notice that I have moved the closing of the anchor into the `for` and `br` is added if and only if `i` is odd. You can increase the `width` of every pair anchor using CSS if you need to do that.